# MySQL; Import .SQL and replace single column

Tags: mysql, sql, import, phpmyadmin

Let's say I have the following table in my MySQL database:

```
id item   value
 1 Plump  A
 2 Apple  B
 3 Banana F
 4 Peach  K
 5 Orange B
 6 Cherry U
```

And I have this table on my computer:

```
id value
 1 B
 2 F
 3 L
 4 A
 5 B
 6 A
```

I want to import the table from computer and replace the values from `value` with the values from `value` where `id` = `id` without changing the values in `item`.

Means, I need this on my MySQL database at the end:

```
id item   value
 1 Plump  B
 2 Apple  F
 3 Banana L
 4 Peach  A
 5 Orange B
 6 Cherry A
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes. It is possible with SET in LOAD DATA Statement. Please refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19237105/load-data-infile-with-select-query-for-data-lookup).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with doing the following in `Apple Numbers`:

[image]

Then copy and paste in something like `Coda`. Search replace tab characters.

Result is:

```
UPDATE my_table SET value = "B" WHERE id = 1;
UPDATE my_table SET value = "F" WHERE id = 2;
UPDATE my_table SET value = "L" WHERE id = 3;
UPDATE my_table SET value = "A" WHERE id = 4;
UPDATE my_table SET value = "B" WHERE id = 5;
UPDATE my_table SET value = "A" WHERE id = 6;
```

Now I just have to execute these SQL codes in my database. Done!